# Integration multi node Couchbase with Springboot

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am new to Couchbase and integrating local Couchbase server from my Springboot application, using Couchbase v6.6 and spring-data-couchbase v 4.0.5

I initially had single node running and my application was able to insert documents using CrudRepository.

I recently configured multiple nodes on my localhost using Docker images, but now my Springboot application doesn’t work as expected.

Relevant section of my logs attached, according to which it looks like the service connects to all 3 nodes, but then immediately disconnects for some reason!

[image]

My config class looks like this…

```
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

  @Override
  public String getConnectionString() {
     return "127.0.0.1";
  }

  @Override
  public String getUserName() {
    return "Administrator";
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return "password";
  }  

  @Override
  public String getBucketName() {
    return "bucket";
  }
}
```

Any helpful tips would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Looking at the couchbase logs, it could be due to an unexpected ServiceDisconnectInitiatedEvent being published, still struggling with this

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your cluster config, are you sure that your clusters can talk to each other and all these IPs are accessible from your app?

Comment: All nodes are running on localhost and the application as well, so accessibility shouldn't be an issue I guess